# Implementing shake to go home Functionality

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

In my application client had a requirement that. When the user shakes the phone he/she should navigate in to the home page. So writing the shake event handler in each page seems bit difficult. Is there any way present to handle this event in a single page like app.xaml, if any one go through similar situation and found a solution please help me too for achieving the functionality

Answer (score 0):

For shake detection you should use accelerometer like described in [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/Shaking-up-your-WP7-app-is-easy-to-do-with-the-Shake-Gesture-Library) article. For presenting it to all pages, you could use

```
RootFrame
```

property in your app.xaml.cs and call it's Navigate property when the shake is detected.